# Materialize Align nav brand-logo center on-med-and-down

Tags: materialize

I have a MaterializeCSS Navbar, which hides all its menu items .on-med-and-down

Because I have aligned my brand-logo on the right it sits pretty awkwardly on the right, when all the menu items disappear into the sidemenu.

Is the a specific class to align the brand logo center "on-med-and-down"?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to duplicate the navbar and create two different version of it.
The big one has the brand logo on the right. This navbar gets the hide-on-med-and-down class 
The other version has the logo in the middle and only gets shown on med-and-down